# Microsoft office Interop word document create from template and close not working

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a console application where I am creating word document using the existing template (using Microsoft.office.interop.word) and saving it. this process is being called multiple times during the complete run of the console application.
So before creating the document, I am checking if it exists already and then delete it before a new one is created. But I am getting error

> the file is used by another process and cannot be deleted

Once the word document is created, I am closing it as well. What is done incorrectly here?

```
    Application variable = (Application)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("provided new guid here")));
                object objAttachpath = attachpath;
                object value = Missing.Value;
                object value1 = Missing.Value;
                object obj1 = Missing.Value;
            Document variable1 = variable.Documents.Add(ref objAttachpath, ref value, ref value1, ref obj1);
//except filename, all other are missing.value
variable1.SaveAs2(ref filename, ref value2, ref obj2, ref value3, ref obj3, ref value4, ref obj4, ref value5, ref obj5, ref value6, ref obj6, ref value7, ref obj7, ref value8, ref obj8, ref value9, ref obj9);
            object value10 = Missing.Value;
            variable1.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges, ref value10, ref value10);
           
            variable.Quit(ref value10, ref value10, ref value10);
            
            variable = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: Have you tried also nulling variable1? I'd also advise to use `try{}finally{}` to make sure, everything is cleaned up in case of an exception.

Comment: Another thing is that the File System may have some "lag". What I did in an application was to give it a retry on error to delete after some 100 milliseconds. If you are already using Polly, you can easily setup a Policy for that or write something yourself if you don't have, want or can use Polly.

Comment: One last thing: If it is the case, that you are creating and deleting the same file over and over and just use the final "version" , you should ask yourself if you can detect the situation and skip to the last creation, so the file is created only once without the need to delete/recreate. A fallback that I also used was to change the filename on error to delete. So, if you cannot delete "newFile.docx" , then create "newFile(1).docx" and clean up some time later.